# Excel VLOOKUP - will need to show up one column from one tab to another excel tab

Tags: excel, vlookup

What is the vlookup format to show the field on the other column based on another column?

What I have is vlookup(A2,'EMAIL ADDRESS'!A1:B5,2,FALSE)
I keep getting #N/A

[image: TAB 1 where I Need to put the email address right next to the student number]

This is the tab where I'm pulling the email from

[image: EMAIL TAB]

Comment: With your provided sample data, the formula you've proposed works successfully for me.  The only way you'd be getting `#N/A` errors is if the Student Number is text that looks like a number in one of the tables, and actual numbers in the other table.

Comment: It should work,  You may need to make the references to the other sheet data absolute: `VLOOKUP(A2,'EMAIL ADDRESS'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)`.  So when it is copied down that reference does not change.

Comment: Is the sheet with the source data called "EMAIL ADDRESS"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted those columns to the same formatting and it looks like it's picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

check if the keys you are comparing are both numeric? or they do not have any extra space that you cannot see.
rest your formula looks fine: Also
put $ sign by your  cell numbers, so that they do not change when you drag them down.

```
vlookup(A2,'EMAIL ADDRESS'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

your formula looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it. It was the format of the cell. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is my recommendation that you make the source data a table. Then you can reference it by table name without having to worry about sheet name or cell numbers and what not.

If you're in Excel 2013 then:

1. select any cell in in the range/area that has the data you want (a single cell, not multiple)
2. **ribbon** > **insert** > **table**
3. then when you're in the table click on **ribbon** > **design** > **table name** and give it a good name (with no spaces)

Comment: This is a very generic optimization response and does not really address OP's question.

Comment: Yes but if you use a table then you wouldn't have to worry about any of the numerous issues you would have otherwise like invalid reference, or cell addresses.

Comment: True, but those would result in `#REF!` errors, not `#N/A`, and doesn't address the main problem.  While I agree that using tables is in general a good idea and helpful for optimization, it's not really relevant to OP's question.

Comment: Understood. Should I delete the answer or leave it?

Comment: Personally I don't mind if you leave it because it is helpful advice